# Laravel queues workers take the same job or duplicates the job

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-queue

I have a problem where multiple workers are taking the same job, even when I have the following settings:

```php
class WaitingForUpload implements ShouldQueue, ShouldBeUnique
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $uploadJob;
    public $tries = 3;
    public $backoff = 60;
    public $timeout = 1500;
    public $retryAfter = 1560;

}
```

On Supervisord I have the following settings:

```sh
[program:waiting_for_upload]
command= php artisan queue:work --queue=waiting_for_upload
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=my_user
numprocs=5
directory=/home/my_user/webapps/my_super_project/html
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)s
```

Any idea on why this could be happening? I'm thinking on setting up multiple queues like "waiting_for_upload_1", "waiting_for_upload_2", "waiting_for_upload_3" but this would be a workaround and wouldn't face the problem.

Comment: check the already running process for the queue system. Maybe there can be more than one process that is currently active on the server.

Comment: Try: (1) killing all worker processes and starting them again (2) clearing the job queue (3) kill all worker processes and then queue a job as normal and then check the queue to see if it only gets queued once